# Unity build file size too large

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a small 2d project with 150 or more textures(png files). Each texture is of about 100kb. When I build the project and check the file, I found the "sharedassets0.assets.resS" file in the projectname_Data folder to be of 432Mb...Then I check editor log and It shows each texture is about 7Mb. How can that happen?...What's wrong with the project?
Thanks!

Comment: Check in inspektor the import settings of your textures. Btw - Unity3D doesn't keep format of imported images - it translates it to its formats that Unity3D support.

Comment: thanks! I disabled mipmaps and set Max size from 2048 to 256 and the build files are just 30Mb(still pretty big though, considering I've only imported two of my texture animation series(60 per animation))...